# Why does my cursor based copying of a table leave the undo tablespace completely occupied even after finishing the procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I am copying a lot of data from one Table to another in a procedure while using cursors to iterate over the data of one table, holding them in an array and befilling the other afterwards in a limited batchsize.

---

I do realize that there are better ways to do this but i devloped it this way because of language restrictions. To my Code:

---

```
    PROCEDURE copy_tableA_into_tableB IS
    TYPE tableA_array IS TABLE OF tableA%ROWTYPE;
    tableA_initialized_array TableIwantToCopyFrom_array;  

    CURSOR table_a_cursor IS
        SELECT *
        FROM TABLE_A; --get all data from Table_A

    BEGIN    
    OPEN table_a_cursor;

      LOOP
        FETCH table_a_cursor BULK COLLECT
          INTO test_copy LIMIT 10000;

        FORALL i IN 1 .. table_a_cursor.COUNT
          INSERT INTO TABLE_B
          VALUES tableA_initialized_array (i);
        COMMIT;

        EXIT WHEN table_a_cursor%NOTFOUND;
      END LOOP;

    CLOSE table_a_cursor;
    END copy_tableA_into_tableB;
```

---

This Code works just fine by just one weird thing that is happening,
when i execute it a couple of times with a bulk of data like 1.5 million table rows the UNDO tablespace is getting bigger and bigger and even though the procedure is done its still allocated by my procedure. Eventually my UNDO tablespace is full and i get an Exception. In fact i can only drop my UNDO tablespace and rebuild it to get it unoccupied and emptry again.

### As you can clearly see i am commiting actually every time i got though the array so why would the UNDO table space even still be allocated after the transaction is done?

---

I am not an oracle expert to understand the underlying concept but i thought my cursor is closed and deallocated when hes closed, so i don't think that hes the culprit, i am using Oracle Version 11g if this is of any concern.

i expected that when i am done with the Procedure that my UNDO table space is deallocated again and i am checking the undo table space that is still left untouched

### EDIT for Questions unanswered:

I am checking how much UNDO tablespace i have left the numbers of data to occupation added up and i am the only one running programms,

Exception: ORA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number with name "" too small

I am testing the procedure in the PL/SQL developer under a stored procedure test
I am not reseting anything just emptying the tables that i wanna copy into with a truncate.

Comment: What queries are you running to see space allocated to your procedure? What exception do you get? When you 'execute it a few times', are you resetting something before each run - like maybe dropping and rebuilding the target table without purging? And what are your flashback settings?

Comment: it will note re use the space if there are a transaction .. you need to wait some time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I don't understand what you mean by "language restrictions". Why would that prevent you from doing a straight insert?

Secondly, you're commiting across a loop - seriously, a bad, bad idea. You could find yourself getting snapshot too old errors.

Thirdly, for your answer, Oracle doesn't immediately free up space in UNDO, once you've finished with it - it's marked as no longer needed (something that you do with that commit, hence why fetching across a loop is a bad idea!) and if another session needs that space then it's overwritten.

Tom Kyte, as ever, [says it best](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5311668500346012409)

Comment: Language restricitons : no changing of the datamodel, aswell as after x datasets a commit.

I should actually add this too all 3 comments but the transaction is most definitely closed. The snapshot be shouldn't be too old since no body uses the table but me.

The fetching part not completly enlightens me to be honest, when its done and the programm goes out of the procedure the localy occupied space should have been deallocated, right ? Obviously i can understand that the undo tablespace is high while i am in the procedure i am just talking after the complete transaction

Comment: If you don't get the snapshot too old error, you're lucky. That's it. Once you issue your first commit, you're telling Oracle that you no longer need any of the data that ended up stored in UNDO. That means any other session is free to overwrite that data and, should your session need to access that overwritten information at some point later on, wham - snapshot too old. See https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:546822742166 for more info.

Comment: As for tidying up of the UNDO tablespace, I'm not entirely sure how that works - my guess is that all the empty space will be filled up first, and then Oracle will go around and search for no-longer-active blocks and overwrite them. There may also be a periodic job to clear down any blocks that are no longer actively in use, but I'm not sure.

Comment: *"after x datasets a commit"* - if you absolutely must batch up the results (seriously, why?) you would do better to have some way of marking the rows to be inserted into blocks and then doing a straight insert (eg. `insert into blahblah select ... from (select row_number() over (order by <some unique, guaranteed when reran order> rn, .... from some_table) where rn >= :start_number and rn < :end_number;`), but this will be slower than just doing an insert: `insert into blablah select ... from some_table;`

Comment: In here are the most valid Informations in my opinion, so i am declaring it as the right answere, anyhow every answere was useful.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle will not reuse space while there is an active transaction there.
that explain why your tablespace completely occupied

More info in this [Undo tablespace keeps growing](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6894817116500)

If you want to know how much space is occuipied

```
select tablespace_name,sum(bytes) from dba_segments group by tablespace_name;
```

this way you can find the actual size

```
select tablespace_name,sum(bytes) from dba_data_files group by tablespace_name;
```

Comment: so from the link that you have posted i understood that the UNDO doesn't go back to 0 useage because it could reuse the space that was allocated from the transaction. But why does it, in my example after the transaction has gone though and i am starting another run rather than reusing his space add more space until hes full ?

Comment: Because it's easier/quicker to insert into empty space rather than overwrite something that's already there, would be my guess

Comment: but it shouldn't be occupied anymore due to the fact that the transaction is most definitely done.

Comment: Oracle doesn't tidy-up blocks immediately if it doesn't have to. Think of when you delete a row - Oracle doesn't tidy-up the space; it leaves the data there but marks it as deleted, so that the next time you insert a row, it might just overwrite that data.

Comment: thats the whole problem, it doesnt reuse this space again its still occupied by my process

Comment: No. The used space reports on blocks that have data in them. It doesn't differentiate between active and non-active transaction data. So even though your transaction has completed (hello commit!), the data is still in the UNDO tablespace, even though it is marked as non-active and available to be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not because the opening statement is:

CURSOR table_a_cursor IS
        SELECT *
        FROM TABLE_A; --get all data from Table_A

Therefore undo is generated so that this query can succeed. The lock on these rows isn't released until after it has completed (by which time the UNDO tablespace is full).

Something like this should work: (some modification to the loop may be required - I personally would check against 'x' processed before commited rather than this method.

```
PROCEDURE Copy_tableA_into_tableB AS
    l_count integer
         BEGIN
         -- Count rows in tableA
        l_count_total := 'select count(*) from table A';
             EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_regexp_count
             INTO l_pancount;
    WHILE l_count > 0
    LOOP
        FETCH table_a_cursor BULK COLLECT
        INTO cdplzstb_copy_batch LIMIT 10000;
        FORALL i IN 1 .. table_a_cursor.COUNT
        INSERT INTO TABLE_B
        VALUES tableA_initialized_array (i);
    COMMIT;
    l_count:=l_count-1;
    END LOOP;

END Copy_tableA_into_tableB;
```